# How to handle taxes related to affiliate marketing?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction, irs, accounting

I'm running a U.S. registered business, selling intangible services online.

Part of my business is offering an affiliate account registration to individuals and companies who wish to earn money through referral sales.

I have a couple of questions regarding taxes handling for affiliates. I've done my search on the Internet but I'm still confused so I hope someone can clarify the following points to me:

1. Is it right that I request form W-9 or form W-8BEN (for non U.S. citizens) from the affiliate users before sending them payments?
2. I know that I have to send form 1099, but I don't know where does this form should go to. Should I send it to the IRS or the affiliate user or both?
3. Should I send form 1099 once a year or each time I make a payment to the affiliate?
4. Do I have to send form 1099 when the money earned by the affiliate hit a certain threshold or I have to send it anyway?
5. Is there any other forms or documents to request from or send to the affiliate user or the IRS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it right that I request form W-9 or form W-8BEN (for non U.S.
>   citizens) from the affiliate users before sending them payments?

Not just OK. **Required**.

> I know that I have to send form 1099, but I don't know where does this
>   form should go to. Should I send it to the IRS or the affiliate user
>   or both?

Both. There's also form 1096 that you need to send to the IRS.  Read the instructions.

> Should I send form 1099 once a year or each time I make a payment to
>   the affiliate?

Once a year. Read the instructions.

> Do I have to send form 1099 when the money earned by the affiliate hit
>   a certain threshold or I have to send it anyway?

$600 or more **requires** the form, but you can send for any amount. Read the instructions.

> Is there any other forms or documents to request from or send to the
>   affiliate user or the IRS?

There may be additional forms. Especially if the recipient is a foreign person and you withhold taxes. Talk to your tax adviser.